# Can I travel into the U.S. with nexus even though my passport has expired?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, canadian-citizens, nexus

I'm looking to travel into the states for the weekend (I live in Canada). My passport has expired but I have nexus. Can I still use nexus even if my passport has expired?

Comment: Before attempting this, you should be absolutely sure that the *airline* is okay with it. Air Canada, for instance, will not allow me to board a flight to the US without presenting my passport, even if I show them my NEXUS card. Furthermore, I feel that this is a scenario where, even if the airline customer service agents tell you that it's fine, the staff at the gate may have a different opinion.

Answer (score 5):

From personal experience, while Saagar's post about using the kiosk is accurate, land crossings using NEXUS during a passport renewal process are fine.  I asked US and Canada customs and they both advised me it was fine, and my following crossing was done during my renewal, using NEXUS, and went without issue.  Flying may be different, though - airlines may want to see a passport, and there may be issues with the kiosks (although the NEXUS card works in Canadian kiosks, and I understand it does now in US kiosks, too, although I've only ever used my passport on the US ones).

Comment: NEXUS doesn't work in US Global entry kiosks. Possibly APC - not had this confirmed by the CBP yet

Comment: @Coke https://www.cbp.gov/faqs/can-i-use-my-nexus-card-global-entry-kiosk According to this, you can use a NEXUS card at Canadian preclearance GE kiosks, but not at GE kiosks anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. If entering at a US airport, a regular desk or possibly APC has to be used

Comment: I asked about this last time I was in a NEXUS office. He thought APC machines won't take a NEXUS card, but GE machines in US airports might if they could match you to an APIS record from an inbound Canada flight. I never had a chance to test this, though.

Comment: I can personally vouch for the fact that NEXUS works when your passport is expired for flying to the US, at least if you use pre-clearance in Canada.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a passport at all.

A NEXUS card alone is valid for entry to the US, even by air if flying from Canada. Same goes for a Canadian enhanced driving licence (by land).

So just show your NEXUS card

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, on the flip side, I just called Canada Border Services Agency asking if I can travel with my Nexus card while my passport is being renewed and they told me it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my information goes, if you do not update the Canadian Nexus system with a new passport number, neither Global Entry nor Nexus will work at the kiosk if you enter the U.S. with your Nexus pass.

As per [Central Border Services Agency](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/contact-coordonnees-eng.html#c1),

> NEXUS members must report to an Enrolment Centre to update or change
>   all other information including:
>
> - Legal Name Changes
> - Changes to Citizenship Documents
> - Changes to Permanent Resident Card Information
> - Changes to Naturalization Certificates
> - Changes to Work Visas or Study Permit Information
> - Changes to Employment Information if the change affects your eligibility to the program
> - Changes to Legal Custody and Legal Guardian Status or Jurisdiction (For all NEXUS members under 18)
> - Changes that could affect your NEXUS membership such as an arrest, a criminal charge, a conviction or a customs or immigration violation
>     in Canada or the United States.
> - Purpose of travel changes (business/pleasure/school, etc)
>
> On occasion, NEXUS will need to contact you regarding program changes.
>   Therefore, please ensure that NEXUS always has your current contact
>   information on file.

Comment: However, it may still be possible to enter with the NEXUS card by walking up to one of the passport inspection desks and presenting the card to a CBP officer.

Comment: @phoog Yes it is, possibly using APC as well (I just know using GE is not possible at US airports)